# Correct paging and coloured output using Git for Windows via Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin

Title says it all: is it possible to get Git for Windows to pipe its output through cygwin's less so that it shows up correctly in a mintty window? There have been a number of questions asked about this, but still no definitive answer.

Arguably this kind of setup is a little esoteric, but
- I need cygwin because I'm using a build system that requires it;
- I don't want to use the git client that comes with cygwin because it is an order of magnitude slower when applying patches or rebasing, which is something I often need to do;
- I am aware that manually typing `git show <whatever> --color=always | less -R` works, but I'm finding it hard to believe that the only working solution is to set up aliases like this for every git command I want paged and coloured output from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out to be surprisingly easy:
`git config --global core.pager 'C:/cygwin/bin/less.exe'`
or
`git config --global core.pager 'C:\\cygwin\\bin\\less.exe'`
will both do the trick. (With the path adjusted to wherever your installation of cygwin lies.) I didn't find this at first because of the need for double backslashes within the quote; but forward slashes work fine too.

Comment: this is not working for me. `which less` provides me with `/usr/bin/less` so I made my config entry as `$ git config --global core.pager 'C:/cygwin/usr/bin/less.exe'`

Comment: I have figured out my issue. My cgwin root is called cygwin64. I changed my config entry to `git config --global core.pager 'C:/cygwin64/bin/less.exe'` and that did the trick. Still confuses me why less gave me `/usr/bin/less` but that wouldn't work in config. Anybody care to explain?

Comment: @Maksim - cygwin's *nix path emulation is a messy business that I never cared to understand well enough to be able to answer that. :) All I know is that there's `cygpath -w /usr/bin/less` to tell you the proper corresponding Windows path (which will however have backslashes, so can't be used directly within the git config command).